# How do you require a base and a derived class to implement a virtual function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I am serializing my class hierarchy, and I want to require both of them to implement a serialization function.

```
class Base
{
  virtual void serialize(File file)
  {
    file << _baseMember;
  }
  int _baseMember;
}

class Derived : public Base
{
  virtual void serialize(File file)
  {
    Base::serialize(file);
    file << _derivedMember;
  }
  int _derivedMember;
}
```

If I always remember to implement the serialize function in the derived classes then everything works fine, but this code as is does not require that `Derived::serialize()` be defined.

My next thought was to create an interface to require that `serialize` be implemented:

```
class Serializable
{
 virtual void serialize(File file) = 0;
}

class Base : public Serializable { ... }
class Derived : public Base : public Serializable { ... }
```

But in this creates the compiler warning `warning: direct base 'Serializable' inaccessible in 'Derived' due to ambiguity`. This makes me feel that something in my design is wrong.

What would be the proper way to require that two classes that are part of the same inheritance chain implement a specific function that is virtual?

Comment: Mm i don't know if you can do that in that way, what about using composition?, having a list of serializable objects and executing his serialize methods, or using a template method calling the serialize for each derived class??, can you give some context for the question?? what do you wanna do?

Comment: When Base aready implements the (pure) virtual function it makes no sense to inherit Derived from Serializable again. Therefore the compiler complains about ambiguity._ What about a template class that takes the current class Base,Derived,... as template parameter and has also a pure virtual method. When you implement the class you must implement that method. But I fear theses are unrelated methods to overwrite. At lest you would have to implement such a function. _ I fear there is NO C++ language featuire that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

The first version is, in my opinion, the correct design. Semantically, why would not Derived be serializable when Base is? Even if Derived does not supply its own implementation? It still "is-a" Serializable.

A workaround might be to do like this:

```
class Base {
    virtual void serialize() {
        file << _baseMember;
        subSerialize();
    }
    virtual void subSerialize() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    virtual void subSerialize() {
        file << _derivedMember;
    }
};
```

Comment: So what happens when I have a `class SubDerived : public Derived` class, how do we make sure that it gets serialized too?

Comment: Is a "chain" of abstract methods, i think is not possible to do what the OP wanna do using only inheritance, each subclass must call the serialize base method and if the subclass is subclassed again, is the same behaviour...